# Progress dialog on View pager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, progressdialog

I am using View Pager for showing 3 Fragments in an activity(Dashboard.java). The activity is loaded after clicking a button on previous activity(Login.java) and two of the fragments are showing a listview which is fetched from the server.

The problem is that it will take at least 3-7seconds to fetch the data from the server and populate as the listview. So I want to show a ProgressDialog to show a Loading status.

I have tried AsyncTask to load the data from the server in the fragment. It works but it show ProgressDialog only after a few time, just for a second before the list is populated. Also there is a delay on clicking the BUTTON to load the main Activity (Dashboard.java)

**So there are two problems:**
1. The progress dialog is appearing very late
2. There is a delay on the previous activity(Login.java) to MainActivity(Dashboard.java) (sometimes show black screen)

**This is my AsyncTask in Fragment**

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

                    pd.dismiss();
                super.onPostExecute(result);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                pd.show();
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


                NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
                // looping through all item nodes <item>
                for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID)); // id not using any
                                                                    // where
                    map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    menuItems.add(map);
                }

                                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
```

Actually where do i should use the ProgressDialog, on MainActivity (Dashboard.java) or Fragment.java ?
Please guide me to the right path.

**EDIT**
Actually what is the best way to load fragments with a progress dialog?
(The fragments are listview which populated from the server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, it was my mistake to write a method out side the doInBackground()

Answer (score 1):

There are may be two solution for that..

1. Start `AsyncTask` at the time of you staring **Dashboard.java** from **Login.java** activity and put starting activity code on `onPostExecute()` of `AsyncTask`. This will help you to loads **Dashboard.java** activity when there is complete data for Fragments.
2. Start AsyncTask in `onCreate()` of **Dashboard.java**. And show **ProgressDailog** in AsyncTask's `onPreExecute()` and cancel it `onPostExecute()` but for this you have some `pre-design layout` for Fragments so user can't see the black screen for **Dashboard.java** activity.

Comment: Second method is not working..

`fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, MenuContact.class.getName()));
  fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, MenuDash.class.getName()));
  fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, MenuHistory.class.getName()));`

These are the fragment call in MAIN ACTIVITY

Comment: The problem is that the ProgressDialog is showing but only after loading all fragments. Means the screen is stuck for a a few seconds and shows PD along with fetched data. Actually I need to show PD in the very beginning. Can you help me?